# Spatial join without temporary layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

I can't find how to perform a spatial join in QGIS without a temporary layer created.
What I want is to update directly the table in the database (Oracle in my case), for a specific column.

Any idea how to do so ?

***Note*** : For this test I have a point layer in which I want to put a field value from a polygon layer which carry this value. So intersect or within is enough to test.

Comment: Can you edit the table in QGIS? If so you might consider using expressions in the Field Calculator, see [this](https://spatialthoughts.com/2019/04/12/summary-aggregation-qgis/) for examples. If not, you would need to use spatially enabled SQL, but if your database setup does not support that, you may still need to create another table/layer with the original table's key/id column and spatially joined data, then non-spatially join that back to the original data.

Comment: I can edit the oracle table in QGIS. The polygon layer is a shapfile. I will dig how to perform the join with field calculator.
Thanks !

Comment: Just to add, that link gives examples of the expressions you can use but you don't need to follow the parts about form widgets and so on. You just need to use a similar expression to update an existing field or create a new field in your points layer using Field Calculator. Such as `aggregate('poly_layer','concatenate',"poly_field",intersects($geometry,geometry(@parent)))`. If the `"poly_field"` is numeric and you expect a one to one join you can use a numeric aggregate function like `sum` or `maximum`, or change data type using `to_string()` to allow the use of `concatenate`